# Send file from web server to a local machine using a...script?

Tags: php, tcp, local, send, transfer

I'm currently in development of a web based project. Majority of the project is either finished, or has a development plan. Let me mention right off the bat, besides my very limited HTML and CSS knowledge that I know very little to nothing of JavaScript or PHP. Which is why I have come here to ask for some advice, or quite possibly some help.

Right now, I have an HTML page with a form that users fill out. this form contains information about their specific options they have chosen. ( the users content is quite irrelevant at this time.)

When they submit, the contents of the form are saved in a .txt file in the root directory of my web server. ( along with the other contents of my site, the HTML, etc.. )

What I need help with or some more knowledge is how I can have that txt file sent to one of my local machine's here, from the web sites server.

The text file will need to be read from my local machine, and based on the user input my local machine will execute some JavaScript locally and what not ( this part of the process already has plan )

You can think of it kind of as a remote viewer/VNC kind of process. Excpet with alot more limitation for security/ease of use pruposes.

If anyone can help or enlighten me on some procedure that would do seomthing to this effect that would be great.

Regards,

Schoolpost

Comment: Why dont you just store the data in an sql database then create a webpage to view the data and browse to it as needed? the you can access it anywhere, not just on localhost, otherwise you will probably need an app written in a computer language, like C

Comment: Thanks for the response, I like the Idea could you go more in depth on how I could possibly do something like that. If not could you explain how it would go about if it there was an app wirtten in C, I have someone who does a lot of C that knows a lot more about it than me. He could probably implement it.

Comment: I personally don't like the idea of using C, if you are submitting things over web programming, why not keep it on the web? you say you have a html/css page for the user to submit a form, take that data and store it in a MySQL database, not a file, files are not for storing data, databases are. Then you could have an admin page that you can browse to like: `www.example.com/admin` but security on it of course. on that page you use php/html/css/javascript to interact with the data that your user put in the database. kind of like your own personal phpmyadmin